# Windows 7 trigger.io starting toolkit fails

Tags: python, windows, trigger.io

I installed the toolkit from Trigger.io but I can't start it. It just gives me this

First I used the simple windows installer, then the Python source - but with the same outcome.

[image: toolkit-local]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause for this error is that your network admin or ISP has implemented a non-standard DNS service which causes the `toolkit-local.com` domain lookup to fail.

You can test this by opening up the windows command line and typing in:

```
nslookup toolkit-local.com
```

The response should contain something like:

```
Name:   toolkit-local.com
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

If this is *not* the case there are two possible solutions:

1. Let your network admin or ISP know that their DNS server has an issue.
2. Modify your developer machine's "hosts" file and add an entry like this:

   `127.0.0.1 toolkit-local.com`

More info on modifying the windows hosts file: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/